# explicit return type when using rxjava2 completable in lambda expression

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

```
Android Studio 3.3
RxJava 2
```

I am having trouble understanding the explicit return for a lambda.

For example I am using clean architecture and in my data layer I have the following interface and implementation (which don't return any completable)

Interface:

```
interface ISendMail {
    fun sendMail(tellNumber: String,
                 membershipNumber: String,
                 attachmentsType: String,
                 message: String,
                 subject: String)
}
```

Implementation:

```
class SendEmailImp : ISendMail {
    override fun sendMail(tellNumber: String, membershipNumber: String, attachmentsType: String, message: String, subject: String) {
        TODO("implement sending the email")
    }
}
```

In my domain layer and this is where I am having a problem:
Interface returns a completable:

```
interface SendMail {
    fun sendEmail(tellNumber: String,
                  membershipNumber: String,
                  attachmentsType: String,
                  message: String,
                  subject: String): Completable
}
```

Implementation and the issue is that the call() wants to return a Completable, but the iSendMail.sendMail returns Unit:

```
class SendMailImp(val iSendMail: ISendMail) : SendMail {
    override fun sendEmail(tellNumber: String, membershipNumber: String, attachmentsType: String, message: String, subject: String): Completable {
        return Completable.fromCallable(object: Callable<Completable> {
            override fun call(): Completable {
                return iSendMail.sendMail(tellNumber, membershipNumber, attachmentsType, message, subject)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

However, If I use the lambda like this, everything works fine:

```
 return Completable.fromCallable {
            iSendMail.sendMail(tellNumber, membershipNumber, attachmentsType, message, subject)
        }
```

Just wondering what is the difference between the 2 different methods, the first which is explicit and expects to return a Completable. And the second that uses a lambda?

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return Completable.fromCallable {
         iSendMail.sendMail(tellNumber, membershipNumber, attachmentsType, message, subject)
    }
```

will generate next java code

```
Completable.fromCallable((Callable)(new Callable() {
        // $FF: synthetic method
        // $FF: bridge method
        public Object call() {
           this.call();
           return Unit.INSTANCE;
        }

        public final void call() {
           SendMailImp.this.getISendMail().sendMail(tellNumber, membershipNumber, attachmentsType, message, subject);
        }
     }));
```

So as you can see `call()` method will return instance of `Unit`. So now to fix problem with your first approach you need to explicitly define type of callable - `Callable<Unit>`

```
return Completable.fromCallable(object: Callable<Unit> {
            override fun call() {
                iSendMail.sendMail(tellNumber, membershipNumber, attachmentsType, message, subject)
            }
        })
```

Now compiler understand that callable should return `Unit`, so it allow to call `iSendMail.sendMail()` without need to explicitly return Unit from `call()` function.